Where and how can I ask about complete lists?
I would like to ask experts a bunch of "list" questions. Generally I'm interested in the vocabulary of a well-educated native speaker of the present-day language.
For example, I would like to have complete lists of non-obscure lexemes of present-day Japanese which use certain extended katakana in their most common spelling, for those extended katakana for which such lists are more or less short. This answer (to the question What "non-standard" katakana are commonly used?) is already great, except I would like something "complete".
I just read this: Should "list of words" questions be discouraged? I should also note that I'm an experienced member of Stack Exchange. Someone suggested to simply search publicly available dictionaries – to which I would like to respond the following (adapted from comments I wrote below an answer to a question of mine):

As an experienced language learner, I have to say that dictionaries tend to contain too much stuff that is not part of the present-day standard language (which is what I normally care about). They also don't have direct frequency information, and words' "most common" spellings occasionally differ from the dictionary's presentation form. This is even truer for collaborative dictionaries. As a beginner, I can't judge or easily research whether a lexeme presented in a given spelling is commonly used, marginal, outdated, or obscure.

This is a real practical problem. I should also note that I'd even pay people to produce such lists for me, though I understand that Stack Exchange isn't used as a forum for freelance job postings.
I would be grateful for advice from experienced members about how far I can go with such questions on this site (and how to phrase them), as well as about where else I could obtain such information or find people willing to help me with such requests.
Rationale: The ultimate goal of such lists is to ease learning for those with high goals. Consider the following example of a list: all commonly used lexemes with voiced geminate consonants.

With such a list, one can learn the relevant items in one go (or one can file the list away to be used as a reference) and then focus on standard orthography.
It's also psychological: it gives you a sense of having practically full knowledge of one aspect; it reduces the feeling of uncertainty about there being additional orthographic quirks the extent of which one is unsure about.
Even if one doesn't immediately memorize such a list, it gives you knowledge about what previously were the unknown unknowns, turning them into known unknowns. With this knowledge, one can then freely decide to ignore certain "known unknowns" and focus on those that one cares about, while knowing the extent/quantity of what one chose to ignore. Basically, such knowledge gives you increased control over the learning experience, just like a vocabulary book with, say, the 12000 most commonly used lexemes does.
Finally, one can use such knowledge to formulate rules for new lexemes one encounters: if a lexeme is newly encountered but not on the list, it's a good assumption that most ordinary (non-specialist) native speakers will use an ad-hoc default spelling instead of an exotic one for it.


What you are asking is essentially a specialized dictionary. As a resource question, it will be on-topic on meta. However, unless you can provide clear criteria of "commonly used", a 'complete' list won't exist just like a complete dictionary does not exist. I don't know what you want that list for, but you should seek a different approach if there's a different goal than just having a list.

@sundowner Thanks a lot; see the rationale I just added.
